# How to add <li> view limit in a div content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add dynamically `<li>` view limit in a div content. I want to show only 3 `<li>` every time when scroll the div content.

I'm not sure but here is an example : http://bit.ly/1fikqQ8

Comment: you need to set `height` with some pixels and then use `overflow: auto` on that `ul` elment

Comment: Is there any way to add dynamically size to show only 3 `<li>` every time when scroll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Old Answer

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bennwbpu/1/

```
$(function(){
    var liheight = $(".demo2 li").outerHeight();
    $(".demo2").outerHeight(liheight*3);
})
```

First we gather the outer height of one `<li>` and we apply thrice of it for the outer height of `.demo2`

If you want to snap to the top of nearest `<li>` every time a scroll event occurs, you can try: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

---

### New Answer

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bennwbpu/7/

Too many lines... but will do. The thing I did to make this solution is a bunch of Googling and putting the pieces together.

**Simplified version**

```
$(function(){
    var lih = $(".demo2 li").outerHeight(),
        lst = 0,
        f=0;
    $(".demo2").outerHeight(lih*3).scroll(function(e){
        var $this = $(this)
            ,st = $this.scrollTop();
        function _scroll(n) {
            $this.css("overflow","hidden").stop().animate({scrollTop:lst+(n)*lih*3}, 500, "swing", function(){setTimeout(
                function(){                    
                    $this.css("overflow","auto");
                    setTimeout(function(){f=0},50);
                },500)
            })
        }
        if (!f) {
            f=1;
            if (st > lst)
                _scroll(1);
            else
                _scroll(-1);
       }
       lst = st;
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes like this.Thanks but can you do this more smoother?

Comment: @Hiptop "smoother"? I'm sorry, I don't get it. I didn't do any animations :/

Comment: I mean i set li height to `2` and when i scroll down it need to scroll to 2 li result. Do you understand?

Comment: @Hiptop so you mean you want the `<li>`s to snap to the top of the frame when you scroll?

Comment: Yes For example : li height `2` and when scroll down it need to come to li `4` .

Comment: Excellent and awesome. Thanks :)